# I am trying achive validation for dropdown error is form is sumbmitting without validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

my form consists this below div:

```js
$("#signup").click(function()
{
   $("#showMessage").html(''); 
   if($("#accountType").val()=='')
   {
     $("#accountType").css({"border-style": "solid", "border-color": "red"     });
     $("#showMessage").html('Please Select Account Type');
     $("#accountType").focus();
     return false;
   } 
   else
   {
      $("#accountType").css({"border-style": "solid","border-color": "#E9E9E9"});
   }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="SignUpForm" class="form-horizontal text-center">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="accountType" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select Account Type</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<select class="form-control" id="accountType">
<option>- Select -</option>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM r_participant_type")or die(mysql_error());
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
?>
<option value='<?php echo $result['id_participant_type'] ?>' s><?php echo $result['name'] ?></option>
<?php } ?> 
</select>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I have few different fields like email and password but this dropdown validation is not working when calling it by id please help me out from this.

Comment: In your option tag you shoud have assign a value of select option. I mean
<option value="">- Select -</option> then only you can check empty validation

Comment: @ShakirAhamed  I am assigning values if you bottom <option value==" php query" i am fteching values from admin.

Comment: @ShakirAhamed thank you bhai i got it..<option value="0" >- Select -</option>

Comment: yeah it's ok but your first option is --Select-- so you have to assign a value to that as empty("") other options values will fill by your php code

Comment: then up vote my comment plz

Comment: where can i up your vote i am new to stackflow

Comment: Go to left corner of my comments their will be a up arrow click that
refer blow link you can learn how to upvote

Comment: it is not appearing i think i need menimum 20 reputation then only i can do that can you rate my question.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i am fetching values in botoom feilds but i am getting it by doing this

```html
<option value="0" >- Select -</option>
```